# Acceptable SNR for a Sound Level Meter

Tags: adc, measurement, sound, specifications, signal-to-noise

I'm designing a low power (<150mW) sound level meter (SLM) using a 24bit ADC (preliminarily using the [LTC2512-24](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/251224fa.pdf)). This is for audible frequency range signals only (20Hz - 20kHz). I'm focused on the portion of the device downstream of the microphone and preamplifier circuitry (i.e. starting with ADC driver).

The important output of this device is LAeq (a frequency-weighted RMS), there will be no spectrum analysis output like FFT or octave.

I'm trying to judge what acceptable SNR will be in my design and as far as I can tell it won't be a challenging issue but I want to confirm I'm thinking about this correctly.

Relevant IEC performance requirements for SLMs are level linearity (+/- 0.3dB error limit) and frequency response (red lines show upper and lower limits):

[image]

Nothing is directly specified for SNR, DR, or THD. I figure SNR will impact linearity and frequency response if it's poor enough although it seems to me this requires absurd noise levels. For example, even with a very poor 20dB SNR, the reported LAeq should have less than 0.1dB error (assuming the noise is broadband and uniform). It seem very easy to find ADCs sporting SNR performance of 90dB or better.

Dynamic range is very important for my application and I'm targeting 110dB, hence the use of a 24bit ADC. This is independent of SNR as far as I can tell; SNR is noise that's only present when there's an input signal and is proportional to the magnitude of that input signal. I can have 20dB SNR and 110dB DR and be fine.

Phase noise from the ADC clock will impact SNR differently depending if it is close-in or not. Close-in phase noise "smears" a pure sine input to a broader peak viewed in frequency domain versus far-out phase noise which adds broadband noise but at a much lower amplitude. Given there will be a frequency weighting filter, the spectral distribution of noise could impact frequency response differently; it strikes me that close-in phase noise is more capable of causing frequency response error. That said, even a very poor 10ns RMS jitter on the ADC clock will give a 60dB SNR for a 20kHz input signal, so clock jitter seems not a particularly challenging design constraint.

Am I misunderstanding or missing anything?

Comment: Looks like you are on the right lines. SNR has to be absurdly poor to affect measurement accuracy ... BUT remember you have to maintain that accuracy even at very low sound levels. So if you really mean a 110dB measurement range, -20dB SNR at the bottom implies -130dBfs.

Comment: I found a great sound meter for windows that is free with all the calibration , measurement, generators  and spectral density plots.  But an acceptable SNR starts with a low Noise figure front end and 110 dB range might work better with a 24 bit SDC and an anechoic faraday cage to get the 1 phonem ambient level which is really hard to make without standing 1/4 wave Ricean notches

Comment: What kind of noises are you trying to measure?  If its continuous (like, ambient room noise), then that simplifies the need. Given your simple need for just one single output reading, I don't understand why you need 24-bits. You can use a low-noise pre-amp in front of the A/D to pre-process the signal. Then the A/D needs to only handle a much narrower dynamic range. If, however, the noise is unpredictable, intermittent, or you need to capture brief "pulse", then I see how you might choose this approach,

Comment: @RichS the same device needs to be able to measure very distant quiet sounds typical of a rural environment, and very close loud sounds typical of an urban environment. I suppose this could be done with a lower bitrate converter and a switchable gain analog frontend since there's no single environment likely to need the full 24bit range, but that comes with some user experience downsides.